# Adding a line break to a string from plist in iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, line-breaks

I need to add a line break to a string, which I obtain from the plist. The string is passed to the `UILabel` to presented on screen.
 For example, my text is like `"Adding a line break to a string from plist in iOS"`
 I need a line break after the word break.

I have added a `"\n"`, hence the text became "Adding a line break \n to a string from plist in iOS". Ensured the `numberoflines = 0` for the `UILabel`.

But I can't see the line break and the text `"\n"` appears in the text itself.

Need some guidance on this.. Thanks..

EDIT:

```
[photo setCaption:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[galleryArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"Title"]]];
```

Comment: can you show code how you obtain your string from the plist?

Comment: Something to do with encoding I guess.

Comment: Do you want the newline in the string in the plist file? Just type "option-Return" while editing the string in the plist editor. This will put a newline in the value.

Comment: Side note - in your edit, get rid of your use of `stringWithFormat`. Just use: `[photo setCaption:[[galleryArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"Title"]];`

Comment: I've tried the same and for me it's working on both iOS 5 and 6: `self.label.text = @"test\ntext";`

Comment: @Levi There is a huge difference between using the `\n` character literal in an `NSString` literal and typing the characters \ and `n` into the string value in a plist file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The plist file requires an actual newline character in the string value. You can't enter the two characters \ and `n`. Those are only treated as a newline character by the compiler.

Bring up the plist file in Xcode and edit the string value. To enter a newline, press `option-Return` on your keyboard instead of just `Return`.

Now when you load this string value into an `NSString` in your app, the newline will be part of the string value. And when set at the text of a label, the newline will appear (assuming the label is setup to show multiple lines).